# Passing a function as a parameter in javascript and not as the function's returned value

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback

Suppose I have a function roll() that randomly returns a value 1-6. Now, if I have another function called repeatFunction that takes a function as a parameter and a number n. The repeatFunction's purpose is to call whatever function it has as a parameter n times. However, if I were to pass roll() as a parameter, the repeatFunction would interpret it as whichever value 1-6 the roll() function returned, rather than a function. My code currently is as follows:

```
function repeatFunction(func, n){
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        func;
    }
}
repeatFunction(roll(), 10);
```

How do I get it so repeatFunction interprets the func parameter as a function rather than a returned value so that I can call it again within the repeatFunction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass a reference to the `roll` function and call it inside the repeat function as a callback. Like this,

```
function repeatFunction(func, n){
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        func();
    }
}
repeatFunction(roll, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the function name rather than the returned execution.

You're executing the function `roll`, just pass `roll`.

```
repeatFunction(roll(), 10);
               ^
```

## Look at this code snippet

*The repeated function will execute the function `fn` recursively until `i == n`*

```js
function repeatFunction(fn, n, i){
    if (i === n) return;
    fn();
    
    repeatFunction(fn, 10, ++i);
}

var roll = function() {
  console.log('Called!');
};

repeatFunction(roll, 10, 0);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

See? the function was called `n` times.